# Attaching / Importing AS3's and MXML in Flex 4?

Tags: php, apache-flex, import, include

Typically, in a PHP setup, you can simply use

```
include('includes/myphpfile.php');
```

to incorporate seperated parts of PHP code and / or HTML markup. Now when it comes to Flex 4, I'm not quite sure how I'd go about doing that same thing, only this time, for ActionScript files. I want to do this kind of approach since my source code gets really annoyingly huge as the Flex app I'm developing grows. That's why I want to separate it into small chunks to avoid getting myself overwhelmed with too much code to see at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you learn about building [Flex Components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4bebcd66a74275c35bf45738120d4f86190-8000.html).  That is the preferred method of encapsulating code and breaking up a single 'file' into multiple components and you'll thank yourself in the long term for learning those skills.

The answer your posted can help you move ActionScript to a different file:

```
<fx:Script source="MyActionScript.as">
```

But it is not the same as building reusable encapsulated codee.  You can also use the include directive to accomplish the same thing:

```
<fx:Script><[[
 include "MyActionScript.as";
]]></fx:Script>
```

The include directive can be used in ActionScript components / classes too, while the Script source attribute is MXML only.

That said, relying on the include file is often considered a crutch and is not a decision I would take lightly.

Comment: I didn't know about the include one since when I try to use it inside an AS3 code block, FB4 doesn't highlight it or suggest it. Is it some kind of a hidden command?

Comment: No, it is not hidden.  More documentation is here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=usingas_4.html

Answer (score 1):

Hey I found out how to do it while Googling around. For those interested, here's what I did:

```
<fx:Script source="myactionscript.as" />
```

Hope that helps others as well!